# Java element of a new List using a Set

Tags: java, list, set, element

I have the method `changePlayer()` that sets an element from the set `players` from the class `Model` as the value of the field `currentPlayer` of `Model`; since I can't get elements directly from a set, so I created a new `ArrayList` using that set.

What I want to know is that if that element created is still using the reference from the old one or has a new reference and therefore any change I make to it will not change the original element from the set created in `Model`.

```
public class Model extends Observable<Change> {

    private Set<Player> players;
    private Player currentPlayer;

    public Model() {
        players = new HashSet<Player>();
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        currentPlayer = player;
        this.players.add(player);
    }

    public Set<Player> getPlayers() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.players);
    }

    public Player getCurrentPlayer() {
        return currentPlayer;
    }

    public void setCurrentPlayer(Player currentPlayer) {
        this.currentPlayer = currentPlayer;
    }

}

public void changePlayer(Model game) {
    Player player2 = new Player(0);//the id in this case is 0

    //this is the part of the code where i create a list using the set
    List<Player> playersList = new ArrayList<Player>(game.getPlayers());

    for (int i = 0; i < playersList.size(); i++) {
        ... // some code that will set player2 by player2 = playersList.get(i)
    }

    // change the current player for the game
    game.setCurrentPlayer(player2);
}
```

Comment: What do your tests tell you?

Comment: You can actually return `new ArrayList(players)` in your `getPlayers()` method, thus users of this method don't need another wrapper collection to be able to modify the list. And they will not run into `UnsupportedOperationException` when they try to add or remove elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only creating a new `List`, but the references in the `List` are still the same references(the reference values are copied but the values still point to the same instances of `Player`, which is similar to no matter how many times of your passport number is copied, the number still identifies you). Thus, if you change the referenced `Player` in your method, you're actually changing the `Player` in your original `Model`, which is obvious, since you haven't created any new `Player` in your method body, have you? The `Player` instances won't just magically be copied since they are not primitive types. There will be only one exception that you're actually cloning all the `Player` instances, which is in your `game.getPlayers()`, you actually deep copied every `Player`. However, this is not what programmers would usually do.